# What results can i expect from nesting a "then.catch" inside another "then" in javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, error-handling

Right now I am working with code resembling a structure like this:

```
doThis().then(() => {
  doThat().then([...]).catch(e => {
    console.log('internal catch');
  });
}).catch(e => {
  console.log('external catch');
});
```

If the interior function `doThat()` ends up returning an exception, will the internal catch, the external catch, or both send messages?

Comment: You can test that using a `throw` statement. `throw "Some error";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, only the internal catch will handle the error thrown by the `doThat` function call. The external `doThis` function won't be aware of what's going on at all. If you want the external catch to handle it, then you'll have to reorganise your code a bit.

```
doThis().then(() => {
  // By returning the internal promise, the external one will
  // now be able to handle both success and error.
  return doThat().then([...]).catch(e => {
    console.log('internal catch');
    // Rethrowing will ensure that the error will propagate to the external handler.
    // Otherwise, handling the error in the catch function will make
    // the promise successful again.
    throw e
  });
}).catch(e => {
  console.log('external catch');
});
```